# setup up ssh connection with 3 Ubuntu machines to bypass a firewall

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, iptables

I have 3 machines, here are the IP addresses of each of them with their ssh port :

`first device IP: 192.168.1.2`

`second device IP" 192.168.1.3 port 22822`

`third device IP: 192.168.1.4 port 22`

I want to SSH with the first device to the second device and connect with the third device, I don't want to use the `-J` flag and `ProxyCommand` in the SSH command the command to connect the third device should be like this :

`ssh user@192.168.1.3 -p 22822`

I should mention that I already did some `ufw` configurations here are the configurations :

Configuration in second device:

`sudo ufw allow 22822`

`sudo nano /etc/default/ufw`

`DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`

`sudo nano /etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22822 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.4:22
COMMIT
```

`sudo ufw disable`

`sudo ufw enable`

Configuration in third device:

`sudo ufw allow 22`

Comment: Provide the verbose client logs and server logs at the time the client attempts to connect by submitting an [edit] to your question.